# Chart js, pie chart remove borderradius

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there any possible way that can i move the pie blue part moved out?

and remove the little spikes on my border?

i've tried looking on the way the border is rendered in the code.

Can anyone helP?

this is how my pie chart looks right now

[image: how my pie chart looks]

UPDATE:

I have removed the weird border. 
Now is the question how i move it more out from the middle... do anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: what have you tried?, whats your code?, when you click on the inspector and check the css rules for the element, what do you see?

Comment: it is an external library from chart.js that renders this chart as an canvas :)

Comment: but the code for creating the canvas is here https://hastebin.com/loquxahupu.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`borderWidth` is your friend

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Green", "Blue", "Gray", "Purple", "Yellow", "Red", "Black"],


    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
        "#95a5a6",
        "#9b59b6",
        "#f1c40f",
        "#e74c3c",
        "#34495e"
      ],
      borderWidth: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
    }]
  }
});
```

Checkout - https://jsfiddle.net/g0tpfL8j/3378/

Comment: but i want to make it like a cutout :) so the blue part sticks a bit out from the circle

Comment: it actually works but, is there a way i can move the cutted out part a bit?

Comment: Sorry @AndersBootsmannLarsen it is not a quick code...  but is definitely possible with extending Chart object - please look at https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2321